# loop to generate a unique url-frinedly route

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table in mariadb in this structure,

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
    `id` char(36), `route` varchar(255), `value` text,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `route` (`route`)
)
```

I use the `route` column to get user-friendy urls, such as http://www.examle.com/this-is-the-route-of-an-item

When a user creates a new item, apart from omitting spaces and illegal characters, I would like to "catch" cases where the route chosen for the new item is in use, and generate a valid route.

For example, if `route-of-an-item` is already in use, i would fallback to `route-of-an-item-a`, or `route-of-an-item-b`, etc.

The naive solution could be querying db in a loop, for example (kind of pseudo code):

```
var additionalChars = "";
while (db.query("select count * from `items` where `route`='" + route + "-" + additionalChars + "'"))
    additionalChars = nextAdditionalChars(additionalChars);

finalRoute = route + '-' + additionalChars;
```

Since this involves querying the db many times I thought of another solution.

```
var additionalChars = "";
var usedRoutes = db.query("select `route` from `items` where `route` like '" + route + "%'");
while(usedRoutes.contains(route + '-' + additionalChars))
     additionalChars = nextAdditionalChars(additionalChars);

finalRoute = route + '-' + additionalChars;
```

Is there any better way to approach this kind of a problem?

Am I correct that the second solution would perform better?

If I use the second solution, should I add a fulltext index to route field?

Comment: Where is `nextAdditionalChars` being defined?

Comment: You could just try to insert it and catch the unique index exception for the db. Then change it and try again. Repeat until you hit success.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is not defined. this is just pesudo code.

Comment: @ojf that is a pretty expensive and unefficient solution, isnt it?

Comment: I don't think so. I do something similar with urls on Mysql with node. I havent benchmarked it but no issues so far. That said, clashes are rare because of the nature of the data, so I have no need to benchmark it.

Comment: How many clashes to you actually get? You should try ojfs idea. Most general solutions will fail because they can clash with another item (see my comment to Axels answer, the same principle applies to monis too). If you are more precise about your numbering (e.g.: addons are numbers, no numbers in your route (or never ending in numbers)), you can use such an approach, but you would need to be more precise about how you chose your addons and your route.

Comment: @Solarflare Im designing a new system, so I dont really know how many clashes I would get, but since the route is based on the Items title, im affraid it could happen occasionaly. ojfs idea is basically the same as the first solution in my question, except I use `count *` instead of catching the db error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after consulting with a colleague I ended up using solution 2, here is the code (node.js), in case anyone faces this problem:

**db access**

```
var route = req.body.route || 'noname';    
route = route.replace(/[\s_]/g, '-').toLowerCase().replace(/[^0-9a-z\u0591-\u05F4\u0621-\u064A\-_\s]/g, "").replace(/_+/g, ' ').trim().replace(/[\s_]+/g, '-');

var isArabic = (/[\u0621-\u064A]/g).test(route),
    isHebrew = (/[\u0591-\u05F4]/g).test(route),
    lang = isArabic ? 'ar' : (isHebrew ? 'he' : 'en');

Items.findAll({ where: { route: { $like: route + '%' } }, attributes: ['route'] })
    .then((items) => {
        var routes = _.keyBy(items, 'route'),
            prefix = '';

        while (routes[route + (prefix ? '-' + prefix : '')])
            prefix = charactersCount(prefix, lang);

        Items.create({ route: route + (prefix ? '-' + prefix : ''), value: req.body.value })
        .then(function(item){ 
            res.send({ item: _.pick(item, ['id', 'route', 'author_id', 'created_at']) })
        })
        .catch(function(){ res.sendStatus(500)});
    })
    .catch(function(){ res.sendStatus(500) });
```

**generate additional characters**

```
var chars = {
    ar: { val: "اﻻبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهةوىي", len: 0 },
    he: { val: "אבגדהוזחטיכלמנסעפצקרשת", len: 0 },
    en: { val: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", len: 0 }
};
_.forEach(chars, (c) => { c.len = c.val.length });

function charactersCount (current, lang) => {
    if (!current) return chars[lang].val[0];
    lang = lang || 'en';
    var curr = current.split(''),
        len = curr.length,
        pointer = len,
        lastIndex;

    while ((lastIndex = chars[lang].val.indexOf(curr[--pointer]) + 1) >= chars[lang].len) curr[pointer] = chars[lang].val[0];
    if (pointer < 0) { curr.unshift(''); pointer++; }
    curr[pointer] = chars[lang].val[lastIndex];

    return curr.join('');
}
```

so I end up with one select query and one inset query, and prevent the clashes in node's side.

and a fulltext index is not needed since the `%` apears only at the end of the `like` operater

Answer (score 1):

You could sort your query by route descending and only retrieve and check one item. In your pseudo code this would look like:

```
var additionalChars = "";
var usedRoutes = db.query("select `route` from `items` where `route` like '" + route + "%' order by `route` desc limit 1");
if(usedRoutes.route is already in use)
     additionalChars = nextAdditionalChars(additionalChars);

finalRoute = route + '-' + additionalChars;
```

Comment: Well, lets assume user a adds `route-name`, then user b, adds `route-name-etc`, then a third user wants to add `route-name` I would want to convert it to `route-name-a` to prevent the clash, but the query in your answer would only tell me about `route-name-etc`, and i could still end up with a clash.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point. You could simply append the id at the end of the route name to produce a unique url. This way you do not need to check anything at all.

Comment: then I could us id for url directly.. my ID is a UUID which is 36 characters long.